# JDBC-EE query - Each row is a message and it runs over and over

Tags: mule, mule-studio

Using MS SQL, and while my query runs and hits the database I have two issues:

-- Each row comes across as a separate message

-- The query will run over and over an apparent infinite times when I only have ~280 items to select

Not clear what I need to add or omit.

Thanks

```
<mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" xmlns:jdbc-ee="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/jdbc" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:core="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" version="EE-3.4.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/jdbc http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/jdbc/current/mule-jdbc-ee.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd">
    <jdbc-ee:mssql-data-source name="Dev_MS_SQL_Data_Source" user="XX" password="XXXXX" url="jdbc:sqlserver://SQLDEV;databaseName=theData" transactionIsolation="UNSPECIFIED" doc:name="MS SQL Data Source"/>
    <jdbc-ee:connector name="Database" dataSource-ref="Dev_MS_SQL_Data_Source" transactionPerMessage="false" validateConnections="true" queryTimeout="-1" pollingFrequency="100000" doc:name="Database"/>
    <file:connector name="Ref_File_Out" autoDelete="false" outputAppend="true" streaming="true" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File"/>
    <flow name="SimpleProjFlow1" doc:name="SimpleProjFlow1">
        <jdbc-ee:inbound-endpoint queryKey="Test__query" queryTimeout="-1" pollingFrequency="1000" connector-ref="Database" doc:name="Database">
            <jdbc-ee:query key="Test__query" value="select ROW_ID, ORDER_NO2, ORDER_NO4 from ShipConfirm"/>
            <!--jdbc-ee:transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN"/-->
        </jdbc-ee:inbound-endpoint>
        <byte-array-to-string-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to String"/>
        <logger message="Message = #[message:payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <file:outbound-endpoint path="\\blat\Dummy" outputPattern="SimpleDBTest__#[function:datestamp:dd-MM-yyyy_HHmm].dat" responseTimeout="10000" connector-ref="Ref_File_Out" doc:name="File"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to associate `ack` query with the select one so that Mule can mark the records that have been processed, for example by setting a flag to `true` while making sure the select query only picks records with the flag to `false`. See: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/JDBC+Transport+Reference#JDBCTransportReference-Acknowledgment

To receive all the records in a single message, transact the inbound endpoint and set `transactionPerMessage` to `true`.

Comment: Thank you David,
This is a Production database on another system so I would prefer not to have to write to it when I am simply querying it.

I suppose if that is the only way to keep it from repeating, I could keep a bookkeeping table around with the IDs and join it and update it which would keep the original table unsullied.

Comment: My Mule Studio is writing bad transaction code so I will hand fix that.


I appreciate your response.

Comment: Yes, adding a control table and joining is an excellent strategy. I don't get the issue with Mule Studio though...